# Convert apache htaccess rewrite rules to nginx rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, rule

Could someone help me to convert this rules for nginx? I need it to serve html as xhtml for svg mask in FireFox

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/xhtml\+xml\s*;\s*q=0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.1
RewriteRule .* - [T=application/xhtml+xml]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is more complex

```
set $var "q";
if ($http_accept ~ application/xhtml\+xml) {
    set $var "q$var";
}
if ($http_accept !~ 'application/xhtml\+xml\s*;\s*q=0') {
    set $var "q$var";
}
if ($uri ~ \.html$) {
    set $var "q$var";
}
if ($server_protocol = HTTP/1.1) {
    set $var "q$var";
}
if ($var = qqqqq) {
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/xhtml+xml';
}
```

not tested